# javascript filter an object

Tags: javascript, filter

i have the following Javascript object.

```
var data = 
{
  "type": [
    "car",
    "bike"
  ],
  "wheels": [
    "4",
    "2"
  ],
  "open": [
    "Jan",
    "Jan"
  ],
  "wheel_press": [
    "35",
    "19"
  ],
  "max-weight": [
    "4000",
    "8"
  ],
  "transition_plan": [
    "",
    null
  ],
  "number_of_occurence": [
    5696,
    976
  ],
  "model": [
    "sedan",
    "street"

}
```

I want to filter on any of the object key to get only the corresponding values for that key.
so far after searching stackoverflow still not able to find  similiar question.
I have tried using

```
data.filter(type ==='car')
```

and the error i am getting is

```
.filter is not a function
```

the expected output is
if i filter on type === 'car'
then it should only show

```
{
  "type": [
    "car"
  ],
  "wheels": [
    "4"
  ],
  "open": [
    "Jan"
  ],
  "wheel_press": [
    "35"
  ],
  "max-weight": [
    "4000"
  ],
  "transition_plan": [
    ""
  ],
  "number_of_occurence": [
    5696
  ],
  "model": [
    "sedan"

}
```

Comment: `filter` is not a function on objects but on arrays.

Comment: `type` is an array. You can't perform `==` on an array. TBH your data structure doesn't make a lot of sense. Your issue here seems to be that, not the code. Without more information on what your trying to do this can't be answered

Comment: You'd make your life easier by fixing the data model of your object. Instead of one object with every property as an array, make one array of objects where each object represents one vehicle (or whatever type your objects are).

Comment: this is how the data i am receiving, I understand the data received is not in the best order.

Comment: @SS_flair Then ask the one that is sending you this data to fix their model. Now it looks like some IKEA furniture where every piece of information is in a different box and you need to construct everything yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function that finds the index of the value inside the given property and then uses `Object.fromEntries()`, `Object.keys()` and `Array.map()` to create a new object as followings

```js
var data={type:["car","bike"],wheels:["4","2"],open:["Jan","Jan"],wheel_press:["35","19"],"max-weight":["4000","8"],transition_plan:["",null],number_of_occurence:[5696,976],model:["sedan","street"]};


const getFilteredObject = (property, value) => {
  const index = data[property].indexOf(value)
  
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(data).map(key => ([key, data[key][index]])))
}

const filteredObject = getFilteredObject('type','car');

console.log(filteredObject)
```

Comment: if the record has multiple records its not retrieving all records with the filter and only retrives the first match record, do i need to add a for loop outside your return statement ?